# Why does adding a View to my layout change the width of the entire layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I added a View to the bottom of my layout to add a line seperator at the end of this element.  The problem is that after putting this View in the layout fills the entire width of the screen but when I take the View out it shows as the correct size (about 400dp in my tests).  Why is the added View causing the layout to fill the whole screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Hello, Label"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_error"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/sr_red"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Error!"/>
    </LinearLayout>


<!-- this View causes the parent layout to fill the whole screen width--> 
     <View
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
         />


</LinearLayout>
```

It is the bottom most  that is causing the problems.

I am modifying the view this way:

```
val inputLayout = createLabelLayout(context, component.name, button)
viewGroup.addView(inputLayout.root)
inputLayout.setWidth(width)
```

And here are the relevant classes

```
private fun <T : View> createLabelLayout(context: Context, text: String, child: T): LabelLayout<T> {
    val layout = LabelLayout(context, child)
    layout.label.text = text
    return layout
}



private class LabelLayout<out T : View>(context: Context, child: T) {
    val root = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_custom_field_label, null, false) as ViewGroup
    val label = root.findViewById(R.id.text_label) as TextView
    val error = root.findViewById(R.id.text_error) as TextView


    init {
        root.addView(child, root.childCount - 1)

    }

    fun setWidth(width: Int) {
        val params = root.layoutParams
        params.width = width
        root.layoutParams = params
    }
}
```

Comment: Your root `LinearLayout`'s  `width` and `height` are set to  `match_parent`. At least it's `height` should be `wrap_content`.

Comment: Right but I'm resetting the width of the root element  when I call setWidth().
And the thing is if I comment out the bottom most view in the xml, (the view that is a divider line)  then the root element formats to the correct width.   So it appears to be the last view in the layout that is causing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed this problem by changing both the root LinearLayout and the child LinearLayout to wrap_content.  Before I was only changing the parent layouts width.